# spring boot redirect to html page

Tags: redirect, spring-boot

This is a controller of springboot, I want to write a function to redirect to an html page, but it always responded with 404, and here is the code and properties.
'

```
@Component

@Controller

@RequestMapping("/Weixin")

public class KindlePocketController {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Autowired
private TextBookInfoSearchService searchService;

@RequestMapping("/homepage")
public String toIndex() {
    System.out.println("redirecting to homepage...");
    return "index";
}
}
```

'
application.properties
'

```
spring.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/

spring.view.suffix=.html
```

'

the program can get into the function and output is ok. And index.html is in this path:/WEB-INF/views/index.html. Is there any else configurations ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: What url you are trying? As per your configuration you should see `index.html` when u hit `http://...contextPath/Weixin/homepage`.

Comment: @SanjayRawat the url is localhost:8080/Weixin/homepage，but it responsed 404

Comment: the atComponent is redundant.  You only need atController.  Not sure if that is causing the problem.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are not using the Spring Boot default location? src/main/resources/templates

Comment: @ccit-spence thanks,I tried this but it did not work

Comment: @ccit-spence you mean the application.properties should located in the path  src/main/resources/templates  ?

Comment: @nasuf no, your views by default can be placed within the templates directory

Comment: @ccit-spence if i put views under this path, how is the spring.vire.prefix should be? i am noy very clear about this

Comment: @nasuf  This blog post provides a decent example of the default templates location http://blog.codeleak.pl/2014/04/how-to-spring-boot-and-thymeleaf-with-maven.html  Sanjay's answer below looks correct by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the incorrect configuration, try this:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html
```

Its `spring.mvc.view.*` and not `spring.view.*`.

PS: Use the Intelisense provided by STS or InteliJ.

Answer (score 0):

This mapping `@RequestMapping("/Weixin")` maps to URL with that name:
Example: localhost:8080/Weixin

Second you have another mapping`@RequestMapping("/homepage")` which maps to URL:
Example2: localhost:8080/Weixin/homepage

You would be redirected to index page whenever you try to access that URL of Example2