# Redirecting to a html file in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to redirect to a html file in my spring boot project.

[Here's my project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lT9Fz.png)

I am trying to redirect to the file /templates/carModel.html

```
@Controller
public class NController {
    @GetMapping("/tester")
    public String tester(){
        return "redirect:templates/carModel.html";
    }
}
```

This is my controller class. The problem is that I do get redirected but, I get redirected to localhost:8080/templates/carModel.html and that doesn't actually show me the file that I want... How do I make this work? Thanks..

Comment: I think you didn't check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37234033/spring-boot-redirect-to-html-page)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Request Mapping for `/templates/carModel.html` or add a Resource Mapping for the HTML files.

But this isn't really the best way to do this.  Ideally, you would have a request mapping like `@GetMapping("/car-model")` and use `/templates/carModel.html` as your View.  Then you can just redirect to "redirect:/car-model";

Comment: `@GetMapping("/carmodel")
    public String tester(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("name", "test");
        return "carmodel";
    }` you meant like this? This started working after I added `spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/templates/` to my `application.properties`